# OR Tools compiled against version 3.5.1 of the Protocol Buffer, not compatible with installed version

Tags: python, installation, protocol-buffers, or-tools

I installed OR Tools on my mac with `pip install ortools`. Now I try to run the example code given by Google on https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#solution.

At the import `from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp` the program crashes with the following message:

> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:86] This program was compiled against version 3.5.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.7.1).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "ortools/gen/ortools/data/rcpsp.pb.cc".)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: This program was compiled against version 3.5.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.7.1).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "ortools/gen/ortools/data/rcpsp.pb.cc".)

I deleted version 3.7.1 of protobuf and installed 3.5.1 with the help of pip:

```
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.5.1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /Users/Martijn/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: setuptools, six
```

But I still get the same error message.. Anyone experience with this problem?

OR Tools:

```
Name: ortools
Version: 6.7.4973
Summary: Google OR-Tools python libraries and modules
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/optimization/
Author: Google Inc
Author-email: lperron@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/Martijn/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: six, protobuf
```

For some reason I cannot upgrade to a newer version of OR Tools with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you upgrade to python 3.6 ?
Latest version (7.0) supports 2.7, 3.7, and 3.7 on mac.

Please note that they were build with 3.6.1.
Next version will include 3.7.1.

Comment: Thank you Laurent, that worked perfect for me! 

For people with the same problem:
I upgraded to Python 3.6.8 (latest 3.6 release) with anaconda using the following command: `conda install python==3.6.8`.